# Insert Or Update in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a method like that

```
private void addDataToDailyStatisticsIncome(String date, String money, int idUser){
    Cursor res1 = db.getDataTableDailyStatistic(idUser);
    int temp = 0;
    int money1, money2;

    res1.moveToFirst();
    while (res1.moveToNext()) {
        if (date.equals(res1.getString(1)) == true) {
            temp = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            temp = 0;
        }
    }

    if(temp == 1){
        money1 = Integer.parseInt(res1.getString(3));
        money2 = Integer.parseInt(money);

        money1 = money1 + money2;

        long isUpdated = db.updateTableDailyStatistic(res1.getString(1), Integer.toString(money1), idUser, Integer.parseInt(res1.getString(0)));

    } else{
        long isInserted = db.insertTableDailyStatistic(date, money, idUser);
    }
}
```

I want to check when new data insert to app. If "`date`" is available, i will update "`money`" in same date. 
Or if "`date`" is not available, i will insert new `Date` with `Money`.

But i have 1 problem that it always inserts, it never updates although i have a same `Date` in `Database`. 
Can you help me fix this problem?

Comment: what data are you getting from `date` and `res1.getString(1)` variable?

Comment: Use debugger and check if (date.equals(res1.getString(1)) == true) this condition

Comment: res1.getString(1) is a type of my Database. And date is a Text of EditText.

Comment: yes that i understand but what **values** are you getting in those variable?

Comment: A Date like 03/05/2016

Comment: and from `res1.getString(1)` ?

Comment: same Date. I display values of Date and res1.getString1. They are the same. 
But i think **temp == 1** never works. So i cant update

Comment: Are formats of both dates same? Have you checked debugging the app?

Comment: Yes. I checked it. But i think 
**while (res1.moveToNext()) {

        if (date.equals(res1.getString(1)) == true) {

            temp = 1;

            break;

        } else {

            temp = 0;

        }

    }**

Is not working. temp's values is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Check if `date` is available and get `money1`:

   ```
   int money1 = 0;
   boolean isAvailable = false;
   String query = "select count(*) from TableName where date = ?";
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {date});
   if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       isAvailable = true;
       money1 = cursor.getInt(money1_column);
       cursor.close();
   }
   ```
2. Insert or Update row:

   ```
   if (isAvailable) {
       // update
   } else {
      // insert
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring date as primary key. Write both sql query (insert and update ) in the the above method.